# How can I make a two-eye-view effect using two cameras?

Tags: unity, camera

I have two cameras. The second was made by duplicating the first.
Then I changed both cameras' viewport rects:

- First Camera `X = 0 Y = 0.25 W = 0.5 H = 0.5`
- Second Camera `X = 0.5 Y = 0.25 W = 0.5 H = 0.5`

Then I created two Post Process profiles for each camera, CC and CC1 in the Inspector.

The result:

[image: Eyes]

But it seems to me a bit odd. Since the view through both eyes looks the same.

Shouldn't the right eye be rotated or something, so it's completing the view from the right side? That is, I don't want both cameras (eyes) see the same (right-hand) view.

Comment: you could also just use one camera, with a mask texture on it that has two holes to represent the player's eyes :) that would solve a lot of problems, since you are simulating how you'd see through the mask

Comment: Did you try offsetting the positions or orientations of the cameras in space to get the effect you want? Changing the viewport rect just changes where the output image gets drawn — it doesn't change the camera's perspective. You need to manipulate the camera's transform in the world (or its projection matrix) to do that.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Are you trying to create some simple stereoscopic effect like with [Google Cardboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cardboard)? If you want to create a VR game, then [Unity does that out-of-the-box](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VROverview.html).

Answer (score 2):

You see, Cameras in Unity are designed to behave like a human eye:

[image: camera]

As you can see from the image above, notional cameras have what's called a *View Frustum*;
To put it simply, it simulates what the human eye would see in real life between a *near* and *far* plane (you can always read more [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingFrustum.html)).

Now let's see how I would solve this:

First of all create a Canvas:

- Go to the hierarchy window, Create -> UI -> Canvas and set `UI Scale Mode` to `Scale With Screen Size`;
- Create an Image object as a child of the newly created Canvas by going (right-click on Canvas) UI -> Image;
- Stretch the image to cover the size of the canvas ( remember to hold down `alt` in order to do so) :
  [image: gif]

Now that you have done that, you could have a "mask" image like these ones for instance (yes, they are both 4k res and you can use them however you want :D):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Remember that when making a mask, the white portion of the image should have an alpha of 0.

- Now that we also have a mask, we can just apply that to the Image we created (when importing the image, remember to set `Texture Type` to `Sprite (2D and UI)`:

[image: 5]

And that's it! To improve even more the effect, you could try making the "lenses" with a gradient, adding multiple layers of textures with different drawing orders to create dirt, or waterdrops, animate the mask to act as an helmet that is being put on / took off ecc..

You can really go crazy with post processing effects too; have fun! :D